# Urllib2 returning HTML with newlines and tabs

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I want to scrape the HTML from some website and then send it off to BeautifulSoup for parsing. The problem is that the HTML returned by urllib2.urlopen() contains newlines (\n) and tabs (\t) as well as having single quotes and other characters escaped. When I try to build a BeautifulSoup object with this HTML, I get an error.

```
b = BeautifulSoup(src)
```

gives [this error](http://pastebin.com/P4kAeSDD).

My code:

```
def get_page_source(url):
    """
    Retrieves the HTML source code for url.
    """
    try:
        return urllib2.urlopen(url)
    except:
        return ""


def retrieve_links(url):
    """
    Use the BeautifulSoup module to efficiently grab all links from the source
    code retrieved by get_page_source.
    """
    src = get_page_source(url)   
    b = BeautifulSoup(src)

    .
    .
    .
```

How can I solve this problem?

**EDIT**

```
import urllib2

link = "http://www.techcrunch.com/"
src = urllib2.urlopen(link).read()

f = open('out.txt', 'w')
f.write(src)
f.close()
```

gives [this output](http://pastebin.com/xyyc2zAj).

Comment: I usually run my HTML through Tidy (it has a Python module) and then parse it with BeautifulSoup. Oddly enough, I have *never* seen that error. You must be parsing some heavily maimed HTML.

Comment: This is the first time I've ever experience this error and I've made plenty of use of urllib2 before.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the HTML you are parsing contains embedded JavaScript code (the BeautifulSoup error complains about line 130, which is in the middle of embedded JavaScript), and the JavaScript contains embedded HTML.

Line 130, notice the `<a>` tag:

```
adNode += "<a href='http://t.aol.com?ncid=...
```

It's [Matryoshka doll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll) of HTML and JavaScript, and Python's built-in parser can't handle it.

You can follow the instructions for installing a parser, given by BeatifulSoup itself in the error message you posted:

> Python's built-in HTMLParser cannot parse the given document. This is not a bug in Beautiful Soup. The best solution is to install an external parser (lxml or html5lib), and use Beautiful Soup with that parser. See http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser for help.